# How many bits do you need to store a positive integer?

Tags: binary, integer

How many bits would you need to store a positive integer for example in the billions? Would you have to use the log2 N to find this out?

Comment: As an integer or floating point and with what precision?

Comment: Signed or unsigned?  That is, are negative integers possible, or are you interested in representing only nonnegative integers?  (I take it from the your question's context that you are speaking of integers, not floating-point numbers.)

Comment: Yes Im talking about positive integers. So would it be the log2 N?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Since I've seen the answer reported incorrectly so many times, I thought I would post the correct answer.

The number of bits needed to represent the positive integer n is

```
bits = floor( log2(n) + 1 )
```

where log2 means log base 2.

Comment: This solution gives me a wrong result with `n = 18446744073709551615` (equal to `n = pow(2, 8 * sizeof(unsigned long))` on a `x86_64` box), because `log2(n) = 64` in this case and `+ 1` is excessive. Are there any cons in using `bits = ceil(log2(n))` instead?

Comment: As @selurvedu points out, despite claiming correctness, this answer is wrong if n is a power of 2. Use ceil(log2(n)) instead.

Comment: @selurvedu, @superdweeble What are you talking about and why people like your comments? `Math.log2(16).ceil` equals `4`, but we need `5`, so `Math.log2(16).floor + 1` is right. `Math.log2((1 << 64) - 1)` equals `64` because of insufficient accuracy.

Comment: @puchu is right, prefer the answer, and please dont upvote the first two comments further

Comment: This answer is wrong. See [this answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12300778/4334743) for the right answer and also its derivation (proof). For example, in Python: `bits_reqd_for_num = math.ceil(math.log2(num+1))`

Answer (score 10):

Yes. the maximal number stored in k bits is 2^k-1, since there is 2^k options for the bits, and one of them is zero.
Therefore, the number of bits required to store a number N is log2(N), but since there is no half bit, you need to round it up to the cloest integer above.

Note: if you need to include negative numbers, there must be one more bit for the sign.

Answer (score 7):

Just to add to the previous answer, you can figure out how many bits are needed to represent a number `N` mathematically using any log-base. For instance, say I want to know how many bits are necessary to represent the number 12345 but my calculator only knows `ln` (natural log).

So,

```
2^b = 12345
```

Taking the `ln` of both sides.

```
ln(2^b) = ln(12345)
```

Of course the log of a number to an exponent is that exponent times the log of only the base, So,

```
b*ln(2) = ln(12345)
```

Divide both sided by ln(2),

```
b = ln(12345) / ln(2)
```

And of course, as is stated in the other answer you will need to round this result up because to represent some number you need 2^b to be equal or greater than that number.

So,

```
b = ceil(ln(12345) / ln(2))
```

Where `ceil(f)` rounds `f` up to the nearest integer.

Using the above process, you can find the number of bits needed for any number `N`, using any log-base `logb`, i.e.,

```
b = ceil(logb(N) / logb(2))
```

Comment: note that if you are using 0-based integers where 000 corresponds to 0 and 111 corresponds to 7, you actaully need to add 1 to this formula.

Comment: To be explicit of what @siemanko is saying, use `b = ceil(logb(N+1) / logb(2))`