# Give a big-O bound on the number of bits needed to represent a number N

Tags: math, big-o, bit, discrete-mathematics

N is random number,

I am confused with bound.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for a random number `n`, there exists `a`, `b` such that `2^a <= n <= 2^b` or just a `k` such that `2^(k-1) <= n <= 2^k - 1` (1). We know that for any number less than `2^n`, we need `log(2^n) = n * log(2) = n` bits to represent it (2). For example:

- 5: 4 < 5 < 8; we need 3 bits for 4, 5 bits for 8 => we need 4 bits for 5
- 23: 16 = 2^4 < 23 < 32 = 2^5; so we need 5 bits to represent 23

In conclusion, for an exact number of bits b for a random number n, we can use the formula:

`b = floor(log(n)) + 1`

So, the big-O notation that we are gonna use is `O(floor(log(n)) + 1) = O(logn)`.

---

Extra info:

- [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269096/how-many-bits-do-you-need-to-store-a-number)
- [Article](https://www.exploringbinary.com/number-of-bits-in-a-decimal-integer/)

---

1) I supposed it is a random, integer, positive number (although it's easy to generalize for negative numbers too) which I suppose it is your problem case; for fractional numbers is's a bit harder to generalize this formulae

2) The log notation refers to logarithm in base 2